# Formatting category description in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I try to bold text on category description [here](http://www.partyxyz.com/category/party-ideas/), but it's still display normal text.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) And [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You may use either this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-html-in-category-descriptions/

or use this sample code in your Function.php

```
function cat_desc_filter( $desc, $cat_id ) {
    // Allow <p> and <a> and <img> <b><strong>
    $desc = strip_tags($desc, '<p><a><img><b><strong>');
    return $desc;
}
add_filter( 'category_description', 'cat_desc_filter' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the following CSS code in style.css
http://www.partyxyz.com/wp-content/themes/sahifa/style.css

```
#main-nav ul li a {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #383838;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
    color: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 900;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 47px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

i have just added font-weight: 900;

Hope this will help you!!